# Appending to the beginning of a text file and then saving as .js for iOS

Tags: javascript, objective-c

**Introduction**

I want to open a txt file and add a new line of text to the beginning of the file. I then want to save the file was a .js file. I've written some code but it appears to be overwriting the original text rather then adding a new line. Also I'm not sure how to save the file as .js file.. is there anything I need to convert?

**Code**

```
    NSString* content = @"test";

    NSString* filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"main" ofType: @"txt"];

    NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filepath];
    if (fileHandle){
        //[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [fileHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [fileHandle closeFile];
    }
    else{
        [content writeToFile:filepath
                  atomically:NO
                    encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                       error:nil];
    }

    NSArray* data = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filepath encoding:4 error:nil] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:0]);
```

**Text in main.txt**

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

**Logs**

> 2014-07-25 15:33:00.631 App1.0[4125:a0b] testEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Comment: That's because you're simply replacing the bytes with new ones, not adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am gonna tell you is probably a bit expensive but it's the best thing I can think about at the moment. 
I would do this way

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"text" ofType:@"txt"];
NSFileHandle *filehandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
NSString *towrite = @"test";

// get the actual content
NSData *original = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
// create a mutable data instance which starts with the string you want to put at the top
NSMutableData *complete = [[towrite dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
// than you append the original
[complete appendData:original];
// and write the data as you already know how
[filehandle writeData:complete];

NSArray* data = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:0]);
```

This will print:

```
testABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Tested myself and working.

Hope it helps.

p.S. It might be a bit too expensive when it comes to really huge files.

For the second part of your question I would do this way:

Get the file path you want to write to, adding the extension .js

And then do something similar to:

```
[complete writeToFile:pathToFileWithJSExtension];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sir you are legendary